# Trying to calculate my total price in real-time, but instead, the totals for each company are being displayed at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning JavaScript and I am struggling with the following issue. I created a form and I would like the total amount to be updated and displayed according to the radio buttons that the user clicks. 
Example: if the user clicks on NB distribution and Joey's trucking, the total should display $98.00. If the user clicks all 3 buttons, the total should be 488 and etc. etc.

However, when I click a company, doesn't matter which one of the three it is, I get the totals for each company displayed at once. It looks like this: 03904949

This is my first time working with real-time updates in JavaScript, so any help and an explanation of what I am doing wrong is more than welcome.

```js
function updateTotal () {
  total = 0;
  total += frm.acme_bill.value  + frm.nb_bill.value + frm.joey_bill.value;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
            <h1>ABC Corp</h1>
            <h4>Bill for the month of: June</h4>
            <h4>Payment due: 5/10/2020</h4>
            <hr />
            <form  action="" id="frm">
                <table id="billing">
                    <tr>
                        <th width="25%">Company</th>
                        <th width="25%">Pizzas</th>
                        <th width="25%">Orders</th>
                        <th width="25%">Price/pizza</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ACME</td>
                        <td>Cheese</td>
                        <td>10,000</td>
                        <td>$0.039</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="radio1" id="radio1">
                                <input type="radio" value="390" name="acme_bill"onclick="updateTotal()">
                                <label for="regular">390.00</label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>NB Distribution</td>
                        <td>Sausage</td>
                        <td>1,000</td>
                        <td>$0.049</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="radio1" id="radio2">
                                <input type="radio" value="49" name="nb_bill" onclick="updateTotal()">
                                <label for="regular">49.00</label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Joey's Trucking</td>
                        <td>Pepporini</td>
                        <td>1,000</td>
                        <td>$0.049</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="radio1" id="radio3">
                                <input type="radio" value="49" name="joey_bill" onclick="updateTotal()">
                                <label for="regular">49.00</label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            <hr>
            <div id="total"></div>
            <hr>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're not checking whether the button is checked or not. Also, you need to convert the value to a number so you get addition instead of concatenation.

Comment: You should use checkboxes instead of radio buttons. Radio buttons are for choosing between multiple options.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the value to the total only if it's checked.

I've changed it from a radio button to a checkbox below, because you can't uncheck a radio button (unless you select a different button in the same group, but you don't have any groups).

```js
function updateTotal() {
  total = 0;
  frm.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").forEach(input => {
    if (input.checked) {
      total += parseFloat(input.value);
    }
  });
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <h1>ABC Corp</h1>
    <h4>Bill for the month of: June</h4>
    <h4>Payment due: 5/10/2020</h4>
    <hr />
    <form action="" id="frm">
      <table id="billing">
        <tr>
          <th width="25%">Company</th>
          <th width="25%">Pizzas</th>
          <th width="25%">Orders</th>
          <th width="25%">Price/pizza</th>
          <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ACME</td>
          <td>Cheese</td>
          <td>10,000</td>
          <td>$0.039</td>
          <td>
            <div class="radio1" id="radio1">
              <input type="checkbox" value="390" name="acme_bill" onclick="updateTotal()">
              <label for="regular">390.00</label>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>NB Distribution</td>
          <td>Sausage</td>
          <td>1,000</td>
          <td>$0.049</td>
          <td>
            <div class="radio1" id="radio2">
              <input type="checkbox" value="49" name="nb_bill" onclick="updateTotal()">
              <label for="regular">49.00</label>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Joey's Trucking</td>
          <td>Pepporini</td>
          <td>1,000</td>
          <td>$0.049</td>
          <td>
            <div class="radio1" id="radio3">
              <input type="checkbox" value="49" name="joey_bill" onclick="updateTotal()">
              <label for="regular">49.00</label>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <div id="total"></div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted all the radio to checkboxes. The I loop through the checked checkboxes and type cast to a number using `+` before the value when adding up the total.

```js
function updateTotal () {
  var _checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
  total = 0;
  _checkboxes.forEach(function(el){
         total += +el.value;
  });

  
  
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
            <h1>ABC Corp</h1>
            <h4>Bill for the month of: June</h4>
            <h4>Payment due: 5/10/2020</h4>
            <hr />
            <form  action="" id="frm">
                <table id="billing">
                    <tr>
                        <th width="25%">Company</th>
                        <th width="25%">Pizzas</th>
                        <th width="25%">Orders</th>
                        <th width="25%">Price/pizza</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ACME</td>
                        <td>Cheese</td>
                        <td>10,000</td>
                        <td>$0.039</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="radio1" id="radio1">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="390" name="acme_bill"onclick="updateTotal()">
                                <label for="regular">390.00</label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>NB Distribution</td>
                        <td>Sausage</td>
                        <td>1,000</td>
                        <td>$0.049</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="radio1" id="radio2">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="49" name="nb_bill" onclick="updateTotal()">
                                <label for="regular">49.00</label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Joey's Trucking</td>
                        <td>Pepporini</td>
                        <td>1,000</td>
                        <td>$0.049</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="radio1" id="radio3">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="49" name="joey_bill" onclick="updateTotal()">
                                <label for="regular">49.00</label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            <hr>
            <div id="total"></div>
            <hr>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the radio buttons if checked or not, also you have to parse the inputs values as [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

```js
function updateTotal () {
  let total = 0;  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked').forEach((el) => {
    total += parseFloat(el.value);
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
            <h1>ABC Corp</h1>
            <h4>Bill for the month of: June</h4>
            <h4>Payment due: 5/10/2020</h4>
            <hr />
            <form  action="" id="frm">
                <table id="billing">
                    <tr>
                        <th width="25%">Company</th>
                        <th width="25%">Pizzas</th>
                        <th width="25%">Orders</th>
                        <th width="25%">Price/pizza</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ACME</td>
                        <td>Cheese</td>
                        <td>10,000</td>
                        <td>$0.039</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="radio1" id="radio1">
                                <input type="radio" value="390" name="acme_bill"onclick="updateTotal()">
                                <label for="regular">390.00</label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>NB Distribution</td>
                        <td>Sausage</td>
                        <td>1,000</td>
                        <td>$0.049</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="radio1" id="radio2">
                                <input type="radio" value="49" name="nb_bill" onclick="updateTotal()">
                                <label for="regular">49.00</label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Joey's Trucking</td>
                        <td>Pepporini</td>
                        <td>1,000</td>
                        <td>$0.049</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="radio1" id="radio3">
                                <input type="radio" value="49" name="joey_bill" onclick="updateTotal()">
                                <label for="regular">49.00</label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            <hr>
            <div id="total"></div>
            <hr>
        </div>
</div>
```

A better implementation would be to have a checkbox instead of radio button:

```js
function updateTotal () {
  let total = 0;  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').forEach((el) => {
    total += parseFloat(el.value);
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
            <h1>ABC Corp</h1>
            <h4>Bill for the month of: June</h4>
            <h4>Payment due: 5/10/2020</h4>
            <hr />
            <form  action="" id="frm">
                <table id="billing">
                    <tr>
                        <th width="25%">Company</th>
                        <th width="25%">Pizzas</th>
                        <th width="25%">Orders</th>
                        <th width="25%">Price/pizza</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ACME</td>
                        <td>Cheese</td>
                        <td>10,000</td>
                        <td>$0.039</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="radio1" id="radio1">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="390" name="acme_bill"onclick="updateTotal()">
                                <label for="regular">390.00</label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>NB Distribution</td>
                        <td>Sausage</td>
                        <td>1,000</td>
                        <td>$0.049</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="radio1" id="radio2">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="49" name="nb_bill" onclick="updateTotal()">
                                <label for="regular">49.00</label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Joey's Trucking</td>
                        <td>Pepporini</td>
                        <td>1,000</td>
                        <td>$0.049</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="radio1" id="radio3">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="49" name="joey_bill" onclick="updateTotal()">
                                <label for="regular">49.00</label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            <hr>
            <div id="total"></div>
            <hr>
        </div>
</div>
```